# Как отправить сообщение после нажатия на ссылку в тг чате

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Хочу сделать бота в тг, чтобы он отправлял сообщение с ссылкой в чат, и после нажатия на ссылку бот автоматически отправлял сообщение. Подскажите, такое вообще возможно? Пока что не понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем вам именно ссылка? Есть inline кнопки, keyboard. По-моему это намного удобнее для пользователя и для реализации. Но, если именно нужно по ссылке, то лично я вижу только 1 вариант реализации. Во - первых вам понадобится сервак с белым айпишником. И внутрь кода бота встраиваете веб сервер, например на Flask. Он обрабатывает `get` запрос соответствующий необходимой вам ссылке и вызывает функцию отправки сообщения в телеге. Возможно какие - то моменты реализации я упустил, но суть должен был передать.